# YQL Yahoo Finance Scraper on XML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, web-scraping

I am using a YQL query (the standard example query, with GOOG, YHOO, MSFT and AAPL) to generate XML for all of the available fields.  I wanted to scrape the YQL site for the XML output once it is generated using a Ruby script, so that I could run it over and over again for different stocks and store the data somewhere.  I haven't finished my script yet, but what I have seems to just not run.  Here is the code:

yahoo_finance_scrape.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'restclient'

PAGE_URL = "http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/"
yql_query = 'use "http://github.com/spullara/yql-tables/raw/d60732fd4fbe72e5d5bd2994ff27cf58ba4d3f84/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.quotes.xml"
as quotes; select * from quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")   '

if page = RestClient.post(PAGE_URL, {'name' => yql_query, 'submit' => 'Test'})
    puts "YQL query: #{yql_query}, is valid"

    xml_output = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
    lines = xml_output.css('#container #layout-doc #yui-gen3000008 #yui-gen3000009 #yui_3_11_0_3_1393417778356_354
                           #yui-gen3000015 #yui-gen3000016 div#yui_3_11_0_2_1393417778356_10 #centerBottomView
                           #outputContainer div#output #outputTabContent #formattedView #viewContent #prexml')

    lines.each do |line|
        puts line.css('span').map{|span| span.text}.join(' ')
        sleep 0.03
    end
end
```

When I run the program, it only prints
"YQL query: use "http://github.com/spullara/yql-tables/raw/d60732fd4fbe72e5d5bd2994ff27cf58ba4d3f84/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.quotes.xml"
as quotes; select * from quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")   , is valid"
And then just stops.  Oh, I am using that Github url because yahoo.finance.quotes was not working, and someone else on Stackoverflow suggested to use it.

If you want to check the css tags, just go to http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ and enter my query and do an inspect element on it.  I would post it here, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

The output is just the content of your yql_query var. so this does not help much.

You probably should not put the "use xxxx ax quotes" as a string in your code.
Check out what "someone else" had in mind.

The `RestClient.post()` method returns a response object. With all HTTP operations, always check the response.code, otherwise you don't know about errors.

```
response = RestClient.post(...)
puts "HTTP Response code: #{response.code}"
if response.code == 200
    page = repsonse.to_str
    ...
end
```

According to the Nokogiri website the xml_output.css() method filters like it is a css selector. if you have for example "#container #layout-doc", this means "filter elements with the id 'layout-doc' inside elements of the id 'container' and so on. Is this really what you itend to do? if yes, the last "#prexml" should be enough and much less error-prone, as ids should normally be unique.

Comment: I will try that last bit out.  I double checked the "use xxxx ax quotes" by manually entering it as a query and it worked, so I don't think that is the source of the problem.  I realize that I don't have any error messages, but how should I tackle this once I've implemented the error handling block?

Comment: Implemented the error handling, still get the same result.  No errors, but no output either

Comment: Apparently 200, because it printed my success message, but didn't do anything after that